# Why does item not adhere to workflow minimum approval status

Tags: workflow, 2013-sp1-hr1

When I edit an item (based on a Schema enabled for Workflow) the item is immediately set to Approval Status "Unapproved"

[image]

When I then try and publish a page, containing the Component, to the Live target (with minimum approval status "Default_Live") it publishes successfully.

I am expecting this to fail, as it does not meet minimum approval status

Comment: Does it publish the .1 version? Or the previous major version? It should still allow to publish the previous major version since that one has an approval status higher than the minimum defined in your target

Comment: (1) Have you installed hotfix CM_2013.1.0.88313. (2) When you say you edit an item and it's immediately set to "Unapproved" you're referring to the in-workflow instance. (3) I presume you've _not_ checked the publish in-worfklow version in the Publish Dialog. (4) _publish the page and it publishes successfully_ - can you confirm if it's publishing the last major version of the content or the _in-workflow_ (minor) version. (5) It would be interesting to see if the 'unapproved' status is retained if you take the item out of the workflow bundle and try to publish without workflow itself at play.

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misinterpreting, this seems to be expected behaviour.

This is because the existing version (which is a major version by default, since you are editing it) has the correct approval status.  Consequently you're publishing the current approved version (say, v3.0) and not the version that's stuck in Workflow (say, v3.1).

I think I'm right in saying that you can only publish a Workflow version via the Workflow script itself, or via some event code to include Workflow items when publishing manually.

I've only ever seen publishing fail due to not meeting the minimum approval status is when we were setting the approval to a lower status when Workflow ended.

Finally, if this is indeed unexpected, double-check the order of the Workflow statuses.  If Default_Live is in the wrong place in the list, then problems may ensue!